# Indentify records from one table through a second table

Tags: sql, union

I think the answer for my question might be relatively simple, but since I've only gotten into SQL since a few weeks, I really don't find a solution for the problem underneath;

I've got three Tables (DIGITAL, PRINTER, ADVERT), that I'd like to merge, based on the EMAIL field (the EMAIL field is unique for every row per table, but there are some overlaps with the other tabels, the other fields should follow the e-mail table, and can't be Queried on);

Current Situation:

DIGITAL

- **aa@aa.com**  -  fname -  lname
- bb@bb.com      -  fname -  lname
- cc@cc.com      -  fname -  lname

PRINTER

- dd@dd.com      -  fname -  lname
- ee@ee.com      -  fname -  lname
- **aa@aa.com**  -  fname -  lname

ADVERT

- ff@ff.com      -  fname -  lname
- **cc@cc.com**  -  fname -  lname
- **aa@aa.com**  -  fname -  lname

Where i'd like to go:

MASTER TABLE

- aa@aa.com      -  fname -  lname
- bb@bb.com      -  fname -  lname
- cc@cc.com      -  fname -  lname
- ee@ee.com      -  fname -  lname
- ff@ff.com      -  fname -  lname

By using the UNION statement, I can come to this result, **BUT** I lose all the other fields apart from EMAIL.

Can someone please help me, I'd be very very very thankfull!

Answer (score 0):

Following query should get you merged result of email, fname and lname:

```
select email,fname,lname from digital
union
select email,fname,lname from printer
union
select email,fname,lname from advert;
```

Comment: Thanks, that one I've already figured out, but; this query compares the three (email fname lname) fields and gives a result based on that. 

I rather want to union email, and then add the fields fname lname, next to it, based on the unique emails left..

But anyway, great thank already for the fast response!

Comment: I'm thinking about a union, combined with the join statement. Is that the way to go?

Comment: Union of email, lname and fname is the way to go. If you just do union on email and try to get names by joining all three tables then it will be overhead. Can you elaborate on why you donot want to join on names and email both.

Comment: because some names who're double, will be treated as unique, because of human spelling mistakes, or even putting fname&lname together in the fname field. You see my point? I got this database from former employees, :p.

Comment: Well in that case your approach is correct, union with join is the way to go.

Comment: héhé thanks! But how do I know I don't miss anything? And can I combine these two statements into one query?

Comment: How will you get the right names? You will pick them from different tables or single table?

Comment: If possible, i'd take the names (and additional info) per ID from max 3 different tables.